# Slick does not commit transaction on AWS postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, slick-3.0

We have an issue with slick 3.0 and a postgres database (9.5) on AWS, where slick opens a transaction but does not seem to commit it, leaving an open connection "idle in transaction" and the futures never complete.

We are just calling `db.run(saveRow(row).transactionally.asTry)`, where

```
private def saveRow(row: Row): DBIO[Int] = {

  val getExistingRow: DBIO[Option[Row]] = table.filter(_.id === row.id).result.headOption

  getExistingRow.flatMap((existingRow: Option[Row]) =>
    existingRow match {
      case None => table += row
      case Some(row) =>
        table.filter(_.id === row.id).map(_.propety).update(row.property)
    }
  )
}
```

Now the first select statement created from `getExistingRow` already does not complete. It works locally, but when running it in production on AWS, all prepared statements are never commited. Logs from `slick.backend` just show

```
#1: Start transaction
#2: StreamingInvokerAction$HeadOptionAction [select ...]
```

We would expect to get the following further logs from `slick.backend` (we see them locally), but we don't see them.

```
#3: SingleInsertAction [insert into ...]
#4: Commit
```

Is there some configuration setting I need to provide for this to work on the side of Slick, HikariCP or the postgres database that could fix this? Any other ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually caused by using the play execution context. When switching to the scala default execution context it worked fine.

Comment: Just to update: This was NOT the solution. Turns out it is caused by a slick bug in which "transactionally" can cause a deadlock if you have too many database requests. See https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1614 and https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1274